# Proof that a 5-gon cannot have fewer than 5 diagonal intersections

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

I figured out that a convex $n$-gon has at most $n\choose{4}$ diagonal intersections.

But how can I show (proof) that a convex $5$-gon cannot have less that $5$ diagonal intersections?

Comment: What does convexity tell you must happen?

Comment: I know that picking any line segment from the interior must be completely contained within the polygon. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @TedShifrin I created a convex 5-gon in GeoGebra and moving a point either makes the polygon non-convex or makes it a quadrilateral. I have no  idea how to describe the situation mathmatically.

Comment: I can create a convex polygon in GeoGebra and move a point without changing the polygon at all. (Just create a point not part of the polygon, and move it.) If the point has to be a _vertex_ of the polygon, I can still move one without making the polygon non-convex or changing the number of sides. Can you say more specifically what you mean by "moving a point"?

Comment: What I meant is that I was not able to move a vertex of the polygon while trying to force less than 5 diagonal intersections without destroying the convex 5-gon. (sorry for my terrible English/explaination)

Comment: So doesn't convexity force each diagonal to intersect two other diagonals? There are 5 diagonals and you count each intersection twice.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't feel that's the way to go. Yes, it's true for convex 5-gons but wouldn't work for 6-gons where diagonals have 3 or 4 intersection points. I am not saying you're wrong, but it's not a prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that the only way for a convex $n$-gon to have fewer than $\binom n4$ intersection points would be in the case where more than two diagonals intersect at one point. If you can justify that claim, and show that it is impossible to get more than two diagonals through a single point of intersection in a convex pentagon, you can prove that any convex pentagon must have exactly five diagonal intersections.

Comment: I accepted your answer because the idea sounds very solid. This is also what I wanted to achieve in GeoGebra. But I can't seem to figure out how to prove this mathmatically. :(